# Diferencia entre super() y ... en herencia, python

Tags: python

tengo una duda acerca de la herencia en python y aunque revise info no pude aclararme.
Al hacer herencia de clases en Python, cual es la diferencia en heredarlo con super().**init**... o con estudiante.**init**... teniendo en cuenta el código.

```
class persona:

    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

    def presentarse(self):
        print(f"Hola, me llamo {self.nombre}")


class estudiante(persona):
    
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        super().__init__(nombre, edad)

class estudiante2(persona):
    
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        persona.__init__(self, nombre, edad)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Juan = estudiante("juan", 99)
    Juan.presentarse()

    Pedro = estudiante2("Pedro", 99)
    Pedro.presentarse()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay una diferencia obvia, y es que cuando usas el nombre de la clase base, como en `persona.__init__()` tienes que pasar `self` (el objeto que está siendo inicializado) como primer argumento. Cuando usas `super().__init__()` en cambio ese argumento no se pone porque `super()` ya retorna el objeto adecuado que será pasado implícitamente como primer parámetro.

Pero la verdadera utilidad de `super()` no es el ahorrarse ese parámetro, sino el no tener que poner "a mano" el nombre de la clase base. Poner ese nombre formando parte del código puede ser fuente de errores si, por ejemplo, te confundes al escribirlo o si, caso más habitual, cambias más adelante los nombres de las clases. Si haces esos cambios de nombre, tendrás que editar y cambiar todos los lugares donde habías puesto el nombre de la clase base. Usando `super()` no hay que tocar el código porque `super()` averigua automáticamente el nombre de la clase base.

También hay diferencias en el caso de la herencia múltiple (una clase que hereda de dos o más clases). En ese caso `super()` te permite invocar un método de cualquiera de sus clases base sin necesidad de especificar cuál de las clases base lo contiene (`super()` buscaría cuál de ellas es). Si dos o más clases de las que heredas implementan el mismo método, `super()` invocará el de la primera que encuentre, siguiendo el *Method resolution order* (MRO), que habitualmente es el orden en que se declararon las clases base (aunque la cosa se puede complicar si estas a su vez heredaron de otras y hay "herencia en diamante").

Un ejemplo de herencia múltiple:

```
class A:
  def saludar(self):
    print("Hola, soy de la clase A")

  def gritar(self):
    print("HOLA, SOY DE LA CLASE A")


class B:
  def saludar(self):
    print("Hola, soy de la clase B")

  def susurrar(self):
    print("(hola, soy de la clase b)")


class C(A, B):
  def saludar(self):
    print("Soy de la clase C y...")
    super().saludar()

  def gritar(self):
    print("SOY D LA CLASE C Y...")
    super().gritar()

  def susurrar(self):
    print("(soy de la clase c y ...)")
    super().susurrar()


c = C()
c.susurrar()
c.gritar()
c.saludar()
```

Produce la salida:

```
(soy de la clase c y ...)
(hola, soy de la clase b)
SOY D LA CLASE C Y...
HOLA, SOY DE LA CLASE A
Soy de la clase C y...
Hola, soy de la clase A
```

en la que se puede ver que encontró el método `susurrar()` o `gritar()` en la clase base que lo contenía, y que en el caso del método `saludar()` usó el de la clase A porque aparece antes según el MRO.

Por cierto que puedes averiguar ese orden de resolución así:

```
print(C.__mro__)
```

---

```
(__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, object)
```